# How many elements/much data can I have on webpage?

Tags: html, performance, dom, browser, web

I recently made some performance improvements to my backend and I decided to take it for a spin.

I tried pushing out 1000 products with images it works fine on all desktop-based browsers, however it made the site crash on my ipad mini. Are there any best practices/performance-tests available? Mobile browsers have their own site and are not included.

To be clear: i don't want to solve the issue on my iPad, I want to know if there are any best practices for DOM-size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you should get your hands on the [TDD](http://enterprisewebbook.com/ch7_testdriven_js.html). For automation  purposes I would strongly recommend [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/index.html) which is a testing framework from AngularJS team.

Karma allows you to run same code to be tested on many browsers or emulated devices simultaneously, it records time of execution and display minor and major errors you might encounter in different environments.

Answer (score 1):

iPads are notorious for crashing due to JavaScript. If you are dealing with a lot of JS, especially JS where execution time increases alongside the amount of data on the page, this could be the cause of your issue.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use Lazy load jquery plugin for loading images in long web pages. Images outside of viewport wont be loaded before user scrolls to them. This is opposite of image preloading.

[Lazy Load Plugin](https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload)